# Rails asset pipeline: Why do my custom fonts work in development but not production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fonts, asset-pipeline

I'm using some custom fonts in my Rails 4.1 application. They are located here:

```
app/assets/fonts/MyCustomFont.ttf
```

I am referencing them in my stylesheet (SASS):

```
@font-face
  font-family: "MyCustomFont"
  src: url("MyCustomFont.ttf") format('truetype')

h1
  color: #fff
  font-family: "MyCustomFont"
```

In development mode, it correctly renders my font. When I deploy to production, I see the font mentioned in the log:

```
** Execute assets:precompile
I, [2014-09-12T23:46:40.077333 #12473] INFO -- : Writing /var/www/apps/10121/releases/c655762f076df708896b622c12429c8bf76f21ec/public/assets/MyCustomFont-18108066511bb5b3ddfd0454b738e8d5.ttf
```

However, when I load the page in my browser it does not render the custom font. The web inspector console shows an error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   http://example.com/assets/MyCustomFont.ttf

When I type in the URL of the font using the filename listed in the log:

> http://example.com/assets/MyCustomFont-18108066511bb5b3ddfd0454b738e8d5.ttf

Then the browser triggers a file download. So it seems like it's just a matter of referencing the file at the wrong location.

How can I solve this problem and what is the correct way to reference a font so that it works in production when the assets are compiled?

Comment: did you try running `rake assets:precompile`

Comment: As I said, the assets are being compiled when I deploy to production (and gave a sample of the log output). You don't want to run that command in development mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Precompilation**

Classic issue - it's basically down to the `precompilation` process of Rails (how it fingerprints the files etc), and your not calling the `dynamic` filepath (which is created as a result of this [precompilation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets) process)

You're calling the following:

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.sass
@font-face
  font-family: "MyCustomFont"
  src: url("MyCustomFont.ttf") format('truetype')
```

This will work in development because `MyCustomFont.ttf` will be available in the assets folder. However, when this is pushed to production (and hence has the fingerprint appended, and moved to the `public/assets` folder), your static reference won't work

Instead, you'll be best using the [`asset_url`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-asset_url) helper:

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.sass
@font-face
  font-family: "MyCustomFont"
  src: asset_url("MyCustomFont.ttf") format('truetype')
```

This will reference the dynamic file - not the static one - meaning the precompilation process should work!

Comment: I learned that you can also call `font_url` and get the same result.